# ¿Por que al realizar un respaldo de una base de dato esta incrementa de tamaño (SQL SERVER)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2008-r2

Consulta, yo tenia mi db en sql server 2008 y lo que fue realizar un backup al sql 2014 luego de esto le volví a realizar un respaldo ya en sql 2014, para restaurarlo en sql 2019 lo que me percate es que ya en el sql 2019 creció el  tamaño de la base , cuando en sql 2008 pesaba 2GB en sql 2019 pesa 15Gb , entonces mi duda es por que hubo este incremento, y si es que se puede volver a su tamaño normal?

Answer (score 0):

verifica si es el archivo de datos(.mdf) es el que creció de tamaño. Lo mas probable sea que el arvhico de registros (.ldf) el que haya aumentado de tamaño. Si es así tienes que reducir o truncar el log de transacciones de SQL server.

```
-- Poner el modelo de recuperación a Simple.
ALTER DATABASE TuBasedeDatos
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
--Reducir el log de transacciones a  1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE(TuBasedeDatos_Log, 1);
GO
--Cambiar nuevamente el modelo de recuperación a Completo.
ALTER DATABASE TuBasedeDatos
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

Verificar el tamaño y la ruta de los archivos .mdf y .ldf

```
sp_helpdb Colegio
```

Comment: Verifique los archivos y me percate que el archivo .mdf es el creció de tamaño al restaurar a la nueva versión de sql, mi duda es por que creció tanto solo por hacer una restauración y si es que se la puede regresar a su tamaño original